# How to pass a signal from one module to another using dot operator in verilog

Tags: verilog

I have got a memory module which consists of a memory

```
module memory(clk,rst,addr,data,wrt,rd); 
reg [7:0] mem [254:0];
```

I am using this memory module in the execute module and I want to use the memory without replicating it again in the execute module.

```
module execute(decoded_instr,clk,rst,instr_in);
if(instr_in[3:2] == 2'b00)
      PR = mem[AR];
    else if(instr_in[3:2] == 2'b01)
      DR = mem[AR];
    else if(instr_in[3:2] == 2'b10)
      GR = mem[AR];
```

One method is to copy the content pointed by the register AR into a temp register in the memory module and use this temp register in the execute module like

```
temp_AR <= mem[AR];
```

and tie temp_AR in the execute module and use temp_AR like

```
      PR = temp_AR;
```

My question is, is there a way to perform the same operation using dot operator and access the memory?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you use the `data` output of `memory` to connect to `execute`? If that doesn't work for you, consider whether what you want can actually be physically made with the resources available in your system (FPGA or ASIC).

Comment: You can use an absolute path as in 'testbench.foo.bar.var'  or access something inside the current module using 'bar.var'. Absolute paths are a pain for everyone other than test folks. Sometimes passing out-of-band signals is indicative of potential for design improvement...

Answer (score 1):

Your approach would not be synthesizable (ie., would not translate into real hardware). You don't want to use a backdoor to your memory array, it's like adding read ports that don't exist.

I'm guessing you are trying to build a pipelined implementation. At cycle 1, read the memory content at address AR. At the next cycle, decode the value you obtained and assign it to PR, DR or GR depending on the decoding. Notice how you don't have to read it again from memory, you already saved it at the previous cycle.